# CouchDB: Return Newest Documents of Type Based on Timestamp

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce, couchapp

I have a system that accepts status updates from a variety of unique sources, and each status update creates a new document in the following structure:

```
{
 "type": "status_update",
 "source_id": "truck1231",
 "timestamp": 13023123123,
 "location": "Boise, ID"
}
```

Data purely example, but gets the idea across.

Now, these documents are generated at interval, once an hour or so.  An hour later, we might the insert:

```
{
 "type": "status_update",
 "source_id": "truck1231",
 "timestamp": 13023126723,
 "location": "Madison, WI"
}
```

All I'm interested in doing is seeing the latest update from each unique source.  I'm currently doing this by taking a map of:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == "status_update") {
    emit(doc.source_id, doc);
  }
}
```

And a reduce of:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  var winner = values[0];
  var i = values.length;
  while (i--) {
    var val = values[i];
    if (val.timestamp > winner.timestamp) winner = val;
  }
  return winner;
}
```

And querying the data as a reduce with `group=true`.  This works as expected and provides a keyed result of only the latest updates.

The problem is it's terribly slow and requires me to `reduce_limit=false` in the CouchDB config.

It feels like there has to be a more efficient way of doing this.  Updating the same document is not an option-- the history is important even though I don't require it in this instance.   Processing the data client-side isn't an option either as this is a CouchApp and the amount of documents in the system is actually quite large and not practical to send them all over the wire.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about updating the document itself, and adding the "old" version as an attachment to the document in question? (and repeating that process for each new status change)

Comment: Wow, truck1231 drives 1,700 miles per hour! Not bad.

Comment: I was waiting for a witty comment there ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the latest timestamp for every source using the [`_stats` built-in reduce function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions), then do another query to get the documents. Here's the views:

```
"views": {
  "latest_update": {
    "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.type == 'status_update') emit(doc.source_id, doc.timestamp); }",
    "reduce": "_stats"
  },
  "status_update": {
    "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.type == 'status_update') emit([doc.source_id, doc.timestamp], 1); }"
  }
}
```

First query `latest_update` with `group=true`, then `status_update` with something like (properly url-encoded):

```
keys=[["truck123",TS123],["truck234",TS234],...]&include_docs=true
```

where TS123, and TS234 are the values of `max` returned by `latest_update`.

Comment: +1 Yeah I forgot about _stats. I believe your first view, `latest_update` answers the OP's question, which is to get the same result but with better performance.

Comment: I wrote stew to solve exactly this problem; however due to a CouchDB bug (require is not supported in reduce functions) it does not yet work. https://github.com/iriscouch/stew

Comment: This is perfect-- I was unaware of the _stats function and it appears to work quite well.  Thanks!

Comment: A `_max` built-in function would be very helpful here, to minimize data transfer...

Answer (score 3):

CouchDB map/reduce is *incremental* which basically means the results are always cached, so subsequent requests for the same view (even with different search parameters) run "for free" (or in logarithmic time).

However, that is not strictly true with reduce groups. Sometimes partial results must be re-reduced on the fly. Maybe that is what you are hitting.

Instead, how about a map view (i.e. no reduce function) that emits rows like this, with an array as the key:

```
// Row diagram (pseudo-code, just to show the concept).
// Key                    , Value
// [source_id, timestamp] , null // value is not very important in this example
["truck1231", 13023123123], null
["truck1231", 13023126723], null
["truck5555", 13023126123], null
["truck6666", 13023000000], null
```

Notice how all timestamps for a source "clump" together. (Actually, they [collate](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation).) To find the latest timestamp for `"truck1231"`, just requests the last row in that "clump". To do that, do a descending query, from the end, with a `limit=1` argument. To specify the "end", use the `{}` "high key" value as the second element in the key (see the collation link for details).

```
?descending=true&limit=1&startkey=["truck1231",{}]
```

(Actually, since your timestamps are integers, you could emit their negation, e.g. `-13023123123`. That will simplify your query a bit but—I don't know—that seems like playing with fire to me.)

To produce these kinds of rows, us a map function like this:

```
function(doc) {
  // Emit rows sorted first by source id, and second by timestamp
  if (doc.type == "status_update" && doc.timestamp) {
    emit([doc.source_id, doc.timestamp], null) // Using `doc` as the value would be fine too
  }
}
```

Comment: Re-reading your question, it occurs to me that you possibly want a "report" type result that gives you the latest update for *all* sources in one big result. If so, let me know. I think there is still room to improve your reduce function. It should not require disabling the reduce_limit so maybe we can debug that a bit instead of this answer.

Comment: This is the case-- with the solution I currently have it means I only have one query to make, but I'm OK with two queries as in the _stats solution and others if it's more performant.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's slow only because you emit the entire document, which means a lot of data needs to be stored and moved around to compute your final values. Try emitting the timestamp instead:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type == "status_update") {
    emit(doc.source_id, [doc._id,doc.timestamp]);
  }
}

function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  var winner = values[0];
  var i = values.length;
  while (i--) {
    var val = values[i];
    if (val[1] > winner[1]) winner = val;
  }
  return winner;
}
```

This should get you an `[id,timestamp]` pair for every key without being too slow or having to store too much data in the views.

Once you have a list of identifiers on the client, send a second request using the bulk GET API:

```
_all_docs?keys=[id1,id2,id3,...,idn]&include_docs=true
```

This will grab all the documents in one request.