# How can I write a timestamp-based map/reduce view to avoid updates in CouchDB?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, cloudant

I’m trying to "avoid updates" in CouchDB which seems to be the recommendation.
But I'm having trouble with being able to make a "reduce" view that returns only the latest value. In the data set below, the document `a8f2298e5961b0ebf60e56022d253d2b` (where s=FooQuux) should basically never be returned, and could be deleted as a "cleanup" operation without impact.

I'd like to be able to do operations such as:

- Retrieve the value for `a` ==> `Bar`

  - [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10392464/185799) could work, using the `s` view, searching for `[["a"], ["a",{}]]` with limit=1.
- Retrieve all values ==>  `a=Bar, b=Quux`

  - Can I write a reduce to "strip out" documents that have an older timestamp?

And for the last two, I'm not sure if it's possible to write one map/reduce view that can do both, given the constraints.

- Get the string length for each user - group=1 == `a=3, b=4` (not counting FooQuux)
- Get the string length for all users - group=None == `7` (not counting FooQuux)

---

Data: (this is a contrived example)

Given data: (where t is a timestamp, u is a username, s is a string)

- at timestamp 0, user `a` set value `FooQuux`
- at timestamp 1, user `a` set value `Bar`
- at timestamp 2, user `b` set value `Quux`

Database:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/all",
  "views": {
    "s": {
      "map": "function(doc) { if(doc.u) { emit([doc.u, doc.s, doc.t], doc.s); } }"
    },
    "slen": {
      "map": "function(doc) { if(doc.u) { emit([doc.u, doc.s, doc.t], doc.s.length); } }",
      "reduce": "_sum"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}

{
  "_id": "a8f2298e5961b0ebf60e56022d251ebd",
  "t": 2,
  "u": "b",
  "s": "Quux"
}

{
  "_id": "a8f2298e5961b0ebf60e56022d253a1b",
  "t": 1,
  "u": "a",
  "s": "Bar"
}

{
  "_id": "a8f2298e5961b0ebf60e56022d253d2b",
  "t": 0,
  "u": "a",
  "s": "FooQuux"
}
```

Comment: OK, so I haven't tried this yet… but I just had the idea that I could make a map like above (`[u, s, t]`) but with the document something like:  { a: { t: 1, s: "Bar" }  }  …  and then the reduce could collect the keys together, throwing out the old ones.   So group=None would be { a: { s:Bar, t:1 }, b: {s:Quux, t:2} }  and other group levels should work as expected…    But for fetching a single "u", the limit=1 approach above would be best, as it wouldn't require a reduce. amirite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not trying to [pull a LEGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Lego#Beginnings.2C_1932.E2.80.931959) but here’s a possible solution:

### Map

per @Glynn-Bird in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39128241/185799

```
function(doc) {
  emit([doc.u, doc.t], doc.s);
}
```

### Reduce

```
function(keys, values, rereduce){
  function rollin(map, u, o) {
    if((!map[u]) || (o.t > map[u].t)) {
        return o;
    } else {
        return map[u];
    }
    return map;
  }
  var m = {};
  for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
      var v = values[i];
      if(rereduce) {
          // merge in this chunk
          for(var u in v) {
            m[u] = rollin(m, u, v[u]);
          }
      } else {
          // roll in single entries
          m[keys[i][0][0]] = rollin(m, keys[i][0][0], {
              s: v,
              t: keys[i][0][1],
          });
      }
  }
  return m;
}
```

## Output

### `reduce=false`, startkey `["a",{}]` endkey `["a"]`, descending, limit 1

This is for "selecting a single specified entry"

```
{
  "value": "Bar",
  "key": [
    "a",
    1
  ],
  "id": "a8f2298e5961b0ebf60e56022d253a1b"
}
```

### Reduce, Group level 1

This is for listing "specific values" (chosen by query)

```
{
  "value": {
    "b": {
      "s": "Quux",
      "t": 2
    }
  },
  "key": [
    "b"
  ]
}

{
  "value": {
    "a": {
      "s": "Bar",
      "t": 1
    }
  },
  "key": [
    "a"
  ]
}
```

### Reduce, Group level None

This is for dumping out all items.

```
{
  "value": {
    "a": {
      "s": "Bar",
      "t": 1
    },
    "b": {
      "s": "Quux",
      "t": 2
    }
  },
  "key": null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By creating a Map function like this:

`function(doc) {
  emit([doc.u, doc.t], doc.s);
}`

You can use the view in two ways:

- to aggregate the data - get counts of the number of documents for values of u (with the _count reducer and `?group_level=1`)
- to select the newest record for a value of `u` - (`reduce=false&endkey=["a"]&startkey=["az"]&descending=true&limit1`)

As the documents are processed separately during indexing, it is impossible to do logic that requires you to know about the contents of another document. i.e. you can prevent a document being indexed at index time, `if(doc.live){ emit(doc.u,null)}` but you can't do "cross-document" logic.

Comment: Thanks!  I think your 2nd bullet is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10392464/185799 for selecting the newest for a specific value.  Is there any way to select the newest for *all* values?  Is that something a reducer could do?

Comment: thinking about this, I might be able to use this view as in my other comment  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091199/how-can-i-write-a-timestamp-based-map-reduce-view-to-avoid-updates-in-couchdb#comment65646827_39091199 - but could I reduce this Map you gave to the format I mentioned in my other comment? Guess I Can try!